# Web Service dll behaving differently in Xamarin from Framework and Core versions

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, soap, xamarin.android

I have a SOAP web service that I need to call in a wide array applications, so I created a service DLL that targets both .net standard 2.0 and .net framework 4.6.1.

The DLL seems to work fine with on Desktop Framework applications, and on Desktop Core applications. However, the behavior on a Xamarin Android project is just *slightly* off of what the other two are.

A correctly sent message from the other two applications looks like this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <ZBAPI_GOODSMVT_CREATE xmlns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
        <CODE xmlns="">
            <GM_CODE>03</GM_CODE>
        </CODE>
        <HEADER xmlns="">
            <PSTNG_DATE>2019-12-08</PSTNG_DATE>
            <DOC_DATE>2019-12-08</DOC_DATE>
        </HEADER>
        <ITEM xmlns="">
            ... data here ...
        </ITEM>
        <RETURN xmlns="">
            ... data here ...
        </RETURN>
    </ZBAPI_GOODSMVT_CREATE>
</s:Body>
```

And the a successfully sent(but not processed) message from the android device is so:

```
    <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <ZBAPI_GOODSMVT_CREATE>
        <CODE>
            <GM_CODE>03</GM_CODE>
        </CODE>
        <HEADER>
            <PSTNG_DATE>2019-12-08</PSTNG_DATE>
            <DOC_DATE>2019-12-08</DOC_DATE>
        </HEADER>
        <ITEM>
            ... data here ...
        </ITEM>
        <RETURN>
            ... data here ...
        </RETURN>
    </ZBAPI_GOODSMVT_CREATE>
</s:Body>
```

So nearly identical, except every namespace inside the body element has been stripped out.
I've confirmed with SOAPUI that **All** the namespaces are needed, even the blank ones.

The DLL in question is, as stated, a .net standard 2.0, and the service was imported using the vendor provided wsdl file.

inside the DLL code I am calling the service like so:

```
private void RunRequest(ServiceData payload)
    {
        var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
        binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.Basic;
        var address = new EndpointAddress("https:\\serviceaddress.com\service");

        new ChannelFactory<ServiceChannel>(binding, address).Using(factory =>
        {

            factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "Uset";
            factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "Pass";

            var proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

            proxy.Open();

            var context = new OperationContext((IClientChannel)proxy);

            var prevOpContext = OperationContext.Current;
            OperationContext.Current = context;
            try
            {
                var results = proxy.ServiceChannel_CREATEAsync(payload).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult().SerivceChannelResponse;
                System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(ServiceChannelResponse));
                using StringWriter text = new StringWriter();
                serializer.Serialize(text, results);
                Message = text.ToString();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        });
```

how can I force the xmlns namespaces inclusion across all platforms?

Comment: if the same code is producing different output on different platforms when using the same framework, I would submit it as a bug

Comment: Duly noted, and I plan to do just that, but first I wanted to check here for a workaround, or see if I'm making a mistake. Since I don't really have time for the likely months long wait while(if!) fix it.

Comment: well, the hacky workaround would be to just insert the namespaces manually before you send